# Load all links inside XWalkView or open a in Intent

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime

I am loading a page using XWalkView.

I would like to know if is possible to Intercept the Load Request of a link in the page, and load it on a new intent popup or stop loading the link.

```
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptLoadRequest(XWalkView view,
                                                          String url) {
        Log.d("shouldInterceptLoadRequ","shouldInterceptLoadRequest " + url);
        return super.shouldInterceptLoadRequest(view, url);
    }
```

this is not called when a page have a link. 
When a page have a link I got a android default popup asking for a browser to open the link.

What I need is to open the google maps app if the url is google maps location.

I did try with the default android WebView but the html5 support is so weak

**Edited**

I should use the

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(XWalkView view, String url)
```

But it look like it have a bug with external links:

https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-3606

**Edited 2**

The problem happen when the link have target="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private XWalkView xWalkWebView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_xml);
    xWalkWebView = (XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkView);
    xWalkWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
    xWalkWebView.load(url_your_want_to_load,null);
}

public class WebAppInterface {
    @org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface
    public void callFunction(){
        // Do your Android Stuff here
    }
}
```

Now Call function in your page as :- `Android.callFunction();`

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed on beta:14.43.343.1

both `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and `shouldInterceptLoadRequest` are working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `onCreateWindowRequested` from the main WebView,
Let a dummy WebView handle the request: just take the URL block the load and open in the system browser.

```
XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.SUPPORT_MULTIPLE_WINDOWS, true);
XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.JAVASCRIPT_CAN_OPEN_WINDOW, true);

XWalkView popupView = new XWalkView(context);

popupView.setUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(popupView){
    @Override
    public void onPageLoadStarted(XWalkView view, String url) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
        view.stopLoading();
    }
});

mainWebView.setUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(this){

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindowRequested(XWalkView view, InitiateBy initiator, ValueCallback<XWalkView> callback) {
        callback.onReceiveValue(popupView);
        return true;
    }
});
```